# Sparse orthogonal complement to vector of ones – name and reference

Tags: matrices, reference-request

#### Preface

I am interested in the following familiy of $n×n$ matrices (empty entries are zeros):

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
\newcommand{\h}{\hphantom{-}}
   1   & \h 1 &  \h 1  & \cdots & \h 1  \\
   1   &   -1 &        &        &       \\
    & \h 1 &    -1  &        &       \\
    &      & \ddots & \ddots &       \\
    &      &        & \h 1   &   -1  \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Such matrices arise when you take the vector of ones (first row) and try to systematically expand it to a basis using only sparse vectors orthogonal to it but not necessarily to each other (the other rows). This problem in turn comes up when trying to transform a dynamical system such that the synchronisation manifold is represented by a single component (the vector of ones).

Empirically, it is easy to see that the inverses of these matrices are:

$$
\newcommand{\n}{\hphantom{n}}
\newcommand{\mn}{\hphantom{-n}}
A^{-1}= \frac{1}{n}\; \begin{pmatrix}
   1   &   n-1  &   n-2  &   n-3  & \cdots &    1   \\
   1   & \n -1  &   n-2  &   n-3  & \cdots &    1   \\
   1   & \n -1  & \n -2  &   n-3  & \cdots &    1   \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
   1   & \n -1  & \n -2  & \cdots &  2-n   &    1   \\
   1   & \n -1  & \n -2  & \cdots &  2-n   &  1-n   \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I am pretty confident that I can prove this if I must (if not I will ask a separate question).

#### Actual Question

Do these matrices have a name? Is there any literature about them and preferably a proof of the inverse? I am asking to be able to avoid a lengthy and tedious elaboration on the subject in a paper and instead be able to just drop a name and a reference.